# What is the maximum data size with xmlhttp GET

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I tried to send my image to the server with xmlhttp. It turns out that it does not work with an dataURL. Is this because of a maximum data size for Get requests?

```
var drawing = document.getElementById("canvas");
var dataURL = drawing.toDataURL();
xmlhttp.open("GET","upload.php?data_sheet=" + dataURL, true);
```

Comment: What exactly is an "imageURL"?

Comment: Sorry, I ment to say dataURL. It is the data from an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how long the content of the `dataURL` is?

The maximum length of a URL is 2048 characters - if it exceeds the maximum length, it will simply cut off the overflow.

Comment: Yes, it was 286000 characters, so way to long.  I think I have to do it with a POST request.

Comment: @Martijn yep -  that would be it! It's generally best to keep things like that to post - a lot more flexibility. Glad you sorted it out!